# error: invalid use of ‘void’ c++ OOP

Tags: c++, oop

```
class Atraccion
{
    private:
        string Nombre;
        int popularidad;

    public:
        Atraccion(){}

        void setNombre(string  nom)
        {
            Nombre=nom;
        }
        string getNombre()
        {
            return Nombre;
        }
        void setPopularidad(int popu)
        {
            popularidad=popu;
        }
        int  getPopularidad()
        {
            return popularidad;
        }

};
Atraccion Atracciones[99999];

void Quicksort(int li, int ls)
{

    int i = li;
    int j = ls-1;
    int tmp,a, b;
    int indice=(li+ls)/2;
    int p=Atracciones[indice].getPopularidad();

    while (i <= j)
    {
        while ((Atracciones[i].getPopularidad())< p) i++;
        while ((Atracciones[j].getPopularidad())> p) j--;

        if (i <= j)
        {
            tmp = Atracciones[i].getPopularidad();
            Atracciones[i].setPopularidad(tmp);

            Atracciones[i].setPopularidad(Atracciones[j].getPopularidad()) =
                Atracciones[j].setPopularidad(Atracciones[i].getPopularidad());
            Atracciones[j].getPopularidad() = tmp;
            Atracciones[j].setPopularidad(tmp);

            i++; j--;
        }

    }

    if (li < j)
        Quicksort(li, j);
    if (i < ls)
        Quicksort(i, ls);

}
```

When I put on set as a parameter function get says me I'm misusing the void as, how i can to spend as parameters to set? I have this problem and can't find a solution

the problem is here 
`Atracciones[i].setPopularidad(Atracciones[j].getPopularidad()) =    Atracciones[j].setPopularidad(Atracciones[i].getPopularidad());`
in this assignation

i try to do a quicksort

Comment: Atracciones[i].setPopularidad(Atracciones[j].getPopularidad()) =    Atracciones[j].setPopularidad(Atracciones[i].getPopularidad()); what is the sense of this line?

Answer (score 1):

`Atracciones[j].setPopularidad(Atracciones[i].getPopularidad());` will return a void (setPopularidad returns void), so you are trying to assign a void to a void `void=void` and you can't do that